# Sección horizontal en SectionList de React native

Tags: react-native

deseo saber si es posible hacer una sección horizontal del component sectionList de react native,necesito que una sección en específico muestre los items de manera horizontal, pero no logro hacerlo. ¿Alguna idea? ya intenté además modificar cada item generado para que sea horizontal pero no sirve.

La sección que quiero muestre los items de manera horizontal está señalada con el círculo rojo.

```
        <View>
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <CellMainNews isFirst={index===0 ? true: false} data={ item } onPress = {item.onPress } />}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
          )}
          sections={[
            {title: 'Top post', data: this.props.featured.top, renderItem: overrideRenderItem },
            {title: 'Featured posts', data: this.props.featured.secundary, renderItem: overrideRenderItemTwo },
            {title: 'Stories', data: this.props.stories},
          ]}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            />

            {this.props.loading &&
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={100} color="red" animating={this.props.loading} />
                </View>
            }
        </View>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITADO**

Funciones que se encargan de renderizar los Items:

```
const overrideRenderItemTwo = ({ item, index, section: { title, data } }) => <CellMainNews isSecundary={true} isFirst={index===0 ? true: false} data={ item } onPress = {item.onPress } />,
```

// CellMainNews

```
if(this.props.isSecundary){ return( <TouchableOpacity style={[featured.column,{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}]} onPress={() => <Image source={{uri: this.props.data.imageUrl}} style={{ flex: 1 }} /> </TouchableOpacity> ) }
```

Comment: @KacosPro Editado, saludos.

Comment: Así es, un arreglo con objetos [{},{} ...] , todos se iteran de manera correcta

Comment: Jajaja así sucede, verás la cuestión es que ScrollView carece del método onEndReached, e implementarlo manualmente trae muchos problemas y no se logra algo estable a comparación de SelectionList, o FlatList,incluso ListView. Incluso intenté modificar los renderSectionHeader creyendo que serían componentes padres de los Items,pero no,todos los items se renderizan igual según el inspector de elementos de React Debbuger. ¿Alguna idea creativa? llevo frito desde hace unas horas pensando qué sería lo más indicado sin tener que recurrir a ScrollView.

Comment: @KacosPro Parece que estoy haciendo un avance,¿Podrías postear unos minutos tu primer respuesta (la de los flatList) ? vi algunos props que me serían de utilidad,sólo unos momentos porfavor.

Comment: Eres bueno, encontré la solución con tu respuesta que parece eliminaste acerca del ScrollView. ¿Podrías postearla como respuesta independiente y la marcaré como la solución? también postearé la solución final en un editado, muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías postearla de manera independiente, y si es mejor que la mía ya no habría necesidad de editar con mi respuesta, sino optar directamente por tu solución :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo te recomendaría para que logres lo que quieres, ya que estás sobrecargando la función `renderItem`, es crear un FlatList o SectionList que, ya que ambos heredan de ScrollView, aparte de tener el prop de `horizontal` tiene el prop `pagingEnabled` que tal vés pueda ser de utilidad en tu caso.

Ya que no necesitas secciones yo me iría por el FlatList

El problema es que renderiza una FlatList por cada item,

¿La solución?

Pasarle un arreglo de un índice conteniendo los items!

```
<View>
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <CellMainNews isFirst={index===0 ? true: false} data={ item } onPress = {item.onPress } />}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      sections={[
        {title: 'Top post', data: this.props.featured.top, renderItem: overrideRenderItem },
        {title: 'Featured posts', data: [this.props.featured.secundary], renderItem: overrideRenderItemTwo }, // Aquí le pasamos en arreglo de un elemento conteniendo los items
        {title: 'Stories', data: this.props.stories},
      ]}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
        />

        {this.props.loading &&
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size={100} color="red" animating={this.props.loading} />
            </View>
        }
</View>
```

Y tu sobrecarga

```
const overrideRenderItemTwo = ({ item, index, section: { title, data } }) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      horizontal={true}
      data={item}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)} // asignar como llave el índice :D
      renderItem={(
        ({item}) => (<CellMainNews isSecundary={true} isFirst={index===0 ? true: false} data={ item } onPress = {item.onPress } />)
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Es una buena idea,pero ya lo había intentado. overrideRenderItemTwo renderiza dos FlatList,debido a que se le pasan dos items, lo que terminan siendo 2 FlatList horizontales (duplicado) ya que overrideRenderItemTwo es llamado cada que recibe un item, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Edité mi respuesta hazme saber si te funcionó

Comment: Excelente @KacosPro , funciona excelente, por último, podrías marcar  la línea donde pasas un arreglo de un índice conteniendo los items ? mi solución fue crear tres componentes dentro de un ScrollView, te tal manera: `<ScrollView><FlatList ... /><SectionList ...props.featured.top/><SectionList ...props.featured.secundary /></ScrollView>` Pero supongo será mucho más eficiente la tuya! saludos desde la capital :D !

Comment: `data: [this.props.featured.secundary]`, y así lograrás lo que quieres sin tener que cambiar mucho código, incluso puedes darle estilo al FlatList horizontal :) Saludos desde la ciudad blanca! Buena pregunta

Comment: Apenas lo noté, interesante solución, en lugar de pasar un item y crear un renderizado por cada uno,pasar todo el arreglo con los items correspondientes para renderizar una única vez, muy buena respuesta, sinceramente nunca esperé encontrar respuesta en el stackoverflow inglés,menos acá,pero me doy cuenta que existe gente muy capaz también por acá,excelente noche, un gustazo! :D

Comment: Un gusto igualmente!